# Remove Separator from iOS TableViewCell Xib

Tags: ios, tableview, separator

When creating a UITableViewCell subclass, the .xib view automatically adds a separator to the bottom of the view:

[image: Xib default separator]

My tableView sets the separatorStyle property to none; however, this gap still appears between random cells at runtime:

[image: Simulator screenshot showing the unwanted gaps]

For the life of me I cannot get this to stop showing the gap randomly or the xib to remove it. There are no attributes I can find to keep this from happening. My Google searches have turned up empty handed about this exact issue.

How do I get rid of this? Any insight is greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try to set `separatorInset` to `UIEdgeInsetsZero` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: 
`if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
    [cell setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}

if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(setLayoutMargins:)]) {
    [cell setLayoutMargins:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
}
`

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that *you* are adding the gap by the way you are designing your *xib* file cell. When I add a vertical bar view to a custom cell in a *xib* file, there is no gap at the bottom, and no horizontal line like the one in your screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is with the top or bottom constraint

check the relative to margin by double clicking on the constraint and also set the constant to 0

[image: relative to margin]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can set this property 
`self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];`
and set the layout like this:([click here](https://github.com/PaulPaulBoBo/TableViewCellGapTest/blob/master/image.png)）

It works in my test code.([click here](https://github.com/PaulPaulBoBo/TableViewCellGapTest))

Answer (score 0):

Simply go to your tableview in xib and select the separator to none: You can refer the image in the link
  ! https://i.stack.imgur.com/noEdE.png

if you are doing it with code you can use:

tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

And for the space you are getting in right side, you can either create Custom TableView Cell, or set the width more and its x axis in negative.

Example. If your superview has width 320, set the tableview frame as:

tableview.frame = CGRectMake(-15, 20, 335, 548)